Is it safe to add the Google firebase admin sdk json file to c# WPF application this way?
I create a WPF application to connect to Google firestore database and everything works fine.I create the firebase admin sdk json file in firebase console:
enter image description here
Then in WPF project, I create the variable pointing to the firebase admin sdk json file as the following:
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\data\adminSDK.json";
then setup the EnvironmentVariable and initialize the database
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", path);
FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create("PROJECTID");
However, I doubt if it is safe to put the Google firebase admin sdk json file in this way?
I find a tutorial showing similar way putting the json file in the project and point to it in code.Reference here:
http://www.dispatchertimer.com/firestore/firestore-2-getting-started-with-firestore-using-c-and-net-core/
However, I doubt if it is safe to put the Google firebase admin sdk json file in this way?
Any suggestion is appreciated
Thank you very much

The .NET SDK from Google itself that the blog tells you to add, is a so-called Admin SDK, intended for use in such trusted environments. You should not use it in apps that you share with non-collaborators.
The GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS it uses provide full administrative access to the Firebase/Google Cloud project. It's like adding the person running the app to your project as a collaborator and giving them full access to the Firebase/Google Cloud console. You should only ever use this on trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.

In non-trusted environments, you'll want to use a Firebase SDK - as those are made for use in client-side applications and can be initialized with just configuration data. Also see Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?
While Firebase/Google doesn't provide a .NET SDK for client-side use, several third party variants of such an SDK exist, such as the ones listed in Using Firebase in .NET.

UnFortunately, none of the c# library such as FireSharp or FirebaseSharp or Firebase Database REST API support Firestore Setup. Any Suggestion?

In that case your only option is to wrap the REST API.

Hello Frank, how to to wrap the REST API? Can you provide me some example? Thank you very much.

Sorry, but how to wrap a REST API in C# is a bit beyond what we can cover here, although that search might have some good results.

Hello Frank, anyway, Thank you for your response and make me clear about the issue.
